# How to fetch a value based on another column

Tags: sas

Please find the dataset below:

```
ID amt order_type no_of_order
1  200  em             6
1  300  on             5
2   600  em           10
```

Output desired:

```
ID amt order_type no_of_order
1  500  on            11
2  600  em           10
```

based on the highest amount i need to pick the order_type.
How can this be achieved in sas code

Comment: Your output does not seem to be coming from your input. Why do the numbers on the line with order_type='on' change?

Comment: They have been aggregated...amt is sum(amt),sum(no of order) ..for order_type..i need to get the value which is against the highest amt

Comment: Do you mean you want the ORDER_TYPE with the highest sum of AMT?  So just one observation?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to get the sum of the two numeric variables for each value of ID and also select one value for ORDER_TYPE.  You appear to want to take the value of ORDER_TYPE which had the largest AMT. Here is simply way using PROC SUMMARY.

```
data have;
  input ID amt order_type $ no_of_order;
cards;
1  200  em   6
1  300  on   5
2  600  em  10
;

proc summary data=have ;
  by id;
  var amt no_of_order;
  output out=want sum= idgroup(max(amt) out[1] (order_type)=);
run;
```

Results:

```
                                        no_of_    order_
Obs    ID    _TYPE_    _FREQ_    amt     order     type

 1      1       0         2      500      11        on
 2      2       0         1      600      10        em
```

Comment: Always love IDGROUP based solutions - one of the most underrated SAS features!